# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, dex, buildpath

How can I solve this? I had tried many things in here, and nothing seems to work for me. 
I had tried importing and cleaning, buildings and restarting eclipse, and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

This error happens when I added a library that is the same I am using in my project, so, I need to exclude the library from my main project and let just the one that comes with the library I imported to my main project.

So,
1. Go to bould path -> Order and Export 
2. Uncheck the jar that is the same that the imported library uses. Click ok.

Now, you are ready to continue developing!

Answer (score 1):

"You have problems with your imports probably your project are using the same two libraries (older and new) and do not know with one should be used.

Check your Libs files, lib-project and references"

Answer (score 0):

I had bad experiences with this annoying issue, it's seldom how both of you explain, older and new but in essence, problem is beyond an older/newer version of a `library.jar`, this problem may also appear i.e. with a class with the same class name `classA` and the same package name `com.same.package` of `libraries.jar` of different vendors.

In this case, we have no more choice than rename a package name or a class name. Another risky choice is to purge a class if we know, we won't use anymore.